# silverlight DataGrid style

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

my Datagrid is:

```
<data:DataGrid x:Name="dgSearchResults" Style="{StaticResource dgStyle}" Grid.Row="1"  ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource dgHeaderStyle}" >
```

I have defined styles in my App.xaml file:

```
<Style x:Key="dgStyle" TargetType="data:DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="RowBackground" Value="#FFF6F6F6"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF3A3B3B"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Verdana"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="13.333"/>
    </Style>
```

**EXCEPTION-->** Invalid attribute value data:DataGrid for property TargetType. [Line: 61 Position: 43]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your App.xaml does not contain the following namespace alias:-

```
xmlns:data="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
```